# Building Pillow for PyPy - unresolved externals

Tags: python, windows, build, pypy, python-imaging-library

I've been struggling with building Pillow for PyPy (2.1) on my Windows (XP) installation, using easy_install.
Problems seems to be related to it missing needed python/pypy header(?). I've been searching Google both up and down  for days, hoping to find a few who could elaborate on the problems I am having, but not finding anything helpful.

The error log I am getting is:

```
...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
/MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IlibImaging -IC:\pypy-21\include -IC:\pypy-21\include /Tc
libImaging\UnsharpMask.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\libImaging\UnsharpMask.obj

...
decode.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Type
encode.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Type
map.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Type
encode.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyString_Resize r
eferenced in function __encode
encode.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetFromErrno
 referenced in function __encode_to_file
encode.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_SystemError
referenced in function __setimage
display.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_Append ref
erenced in function _list_windows_callback@8
display.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Print refer
enced in function _callback_error
display.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFile_WriteStrin
g referenced in function _callback_error
display.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PySys_GetObject r
eferenced in function _callback_error
display.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyObject_CallFunction r
eferenced in function _windowCallback@16
path.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyObject_CallFunction
display.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyThreadState_Swa
p referenced in function _windowCallback@16
display.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyThreadState_Get
 referenced in function _PyImaging_CreateWindowWin32
path.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_ExceptionMatch
es referenced in function _PyPath_Flatten
path.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Check refer
enced in function _PyPath_Flatten
path.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_RuntimeError r
eferenced in function _path_clip_polygon
build\lib.win32-2.7\_imaging.pypy-21.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 61 unresolved ex
ternals
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.e
xe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I really struggle to see why this is happening, I actually have no clue. I am easily able to build packages for CPython.

As far as I see dependencies folder is included as well: "-IC:\pypy-21\include"(?).

For more of the log you can look at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kKnNpRgr

**Edit - The solution**

After grabbing PyPy 2.2.1 I found that I was indeed missing some files in my "PyPy-21/Include"-path. And so.. Pillow installed just fine with the newfound header, and it's running flawlessly! =)

Answer (score -1):

PyPy doesn't implement the entire C extension module API found in CPython.  Or rather, PyPy implements a reasonable subset of the symbols a Cext module is most likely to use, but PyPY couldn't realistically provide every symbol CPython provides without inhaling most of CPython.  I wish CPython were more careful about what symbols it exposes to external code, but I don't believe it is.

PyPy is best with Pure Python modules.  It can run (rather slowly) a subset of C extension modules too.  You may be fighting a losing battle trying to get PyPy to import this particular CPython C extension module.

Bear in mind that you cannot JIT C code in PyPy.

Comment: I am aware that PyPy's CPyExt is not all that compatible. I am building Pillow, which however is PyPy compatible. I was easily able to build Pillow on a Linux distro for PyPy.